# Sitecore SXA - Error Rendering Contoller: DCards. Action: Index: An unhandled exception occured

Tags: sxa, helix

I am trying to build my own SXA custom rendering with a variant by following the articles from Sitecore:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/walkthrough_building_a_new_rendering

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/build_a_rendering_that_includes_variants#_Repository

However, when I tried adding it to my page via experience editor, it appears that I am doing something wrong.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Stack Trace**

```
 at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

I have built the controller, repository, view and register it as dependency -
 backend codes are shown below.

**Controller\DCardsController.cs**

```
using PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.Repositories;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Controllers;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Repositories;

namespace PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.Controllers
{
    public class DCardsController : VariantsController
    {
    private readonly IDCardsRepository DCardsRepository;

    public DCardsController(IDCardsRepository repository)
    {
        DCardsRepository = repository;
    }


    protected override object GetModel()
    {
        return DCardsRepository.GetModel();
    }

    }
}
```

**Models\DCardsModel.cs**

```
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Models;

namespace PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.Models
{
    public class DCardsModel : VariantsRenderingModel
    {
        public string CustomProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Repositories\DCardsRepository.cs**

```
using PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.Models;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Repositories.Base;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Repositories;

namespace PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.Repositories
{
    public class DCardsRepository : VariantsRepository, IDCardsRepository
    {
        public override IRenderingModelBase GetModel()
        {
            DCardsModel model = new DCardsModel();
            FillBaseProperties(model);
            model.CustomProperty = "This is just an example rendering";
            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

**Repositories\IDCardsRepository.cs**

```
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Repositories.Base;

namespace PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.Repositories
{
    public interface IDCardsRepository : IVariantsRepository
    {
    }
}
```

**Views\DCards\DCards.cshtml**

```
@using Sitecore.Extensions
@using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.MarkupDecorator.Extensions
@using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions
@using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Extensions
@using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Fields
@using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Fields
@model IRAS.Feature.Composites.SXA.Models.DCardsModel

<div @Html.Sxa().Component("DCards", Model.Attributes)>
    <div class="component-content">

        <h1>@Model.CustomProperty</h1>
        @foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
            {
            @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.Item, Model.RenderingWebEditingParams)
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**RegsiterDependencies.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.Controllers;
using PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.Repositories;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;

namespace PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA
{
    public class RegisterDependencies : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IDCardsRepository, DCardsRepository>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<DCardsController>();
        }
    }
}
```

**App_Config\Include\Feature\PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <services>
      <configurator type="PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.RegisterDependencies, IRAS.Feature.Composites.SXA" />
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**In Sitecore**

```
/sitecore/templates/Feature/DCards
```

[image]

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature
```

[image]

```
/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/DCards/DCard Content
```

> I believe this is where the issue relies on.

[image]

[image]

```
/sitecore/content/Government/PROJECTABC/MyTaxPortal/Data/DCards/Card1
```

[image]

```
/sitecore/content/Government/PROJECTABC/MyTaxPortal/Presentation/Available Renderings/DCards
```

[image]

```
/sitecore/content/Government/PROJECTABC/MyTaxPortal/Presentation/Rendering Variants/DCards
```

[image]

Any thoughts?

**Update 1:**

I've tried changing the Controller field to: `PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA.Controllers.DCardsController,PROJECTABC.Feature.Composites.SXA` but i received the same issue

Comment: Your stack trace appears to be missing the inner exception. Also, I believe the registration code should be added back/enabled. Also, the constructor should pass in the repository rather than calling the service locator.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue, after publishing and viewing it from the site. It appears that it is because the view couldn't be located.

[image]

Revisiting the rendering name, I realized that SXA is using the item name of the rendering to locate the .cshtml, hence renaming it from '**DCards Content**' to '**DCards**' resolved the issue.